# Which Shakespearean play is Data rehearsing for the opening scene of S03E010, "The Defector"?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, star-trek-tng

If you can identify the act and scene as well, bonus!

Also, it looks like Jonathan Frakes and Patrick Stewart might be playing the parts of the other two characters in the scene. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: Patrick Stewart is indeed playing a holocharacter in that play. But the other one is not Jonathan Frakes, it's actually [Simon Templeman](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0854742/). No-one would let Jonathan to shave his beard just for this scene.

Answer (score 13):

The play is **Henry V**

Lifted stright from the Wikipedia page for [The Defector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Defector_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))

> In addition to his regular role of Captain Picard, Patrick Stewart
> also played the role of the holodeck character of "Michael Williams"
> from Shakespeare's Henry V, Act 4, Scene I